# {{1 + 1}} not being processed in index.html

Tags: angular

I am trying to do following in index.html, unfortunately I am unable to make `{{1+1}}` work in it or say any angular directive. I wanted to know if this is because Angular is not loading before this renders or is there something I need to do for this to work out.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="">
    <script src="libs/shim.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script></head>
<body>
    <my-app>
        {{1+1}}
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/default/app.component';
import { HttpService } from './services/shared/http.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]    
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'this is {{title}}'  
})

export class AppComponent {
    title: string='hello world';
    constructor() { }
}
```

My desired output should be showing **2** till it renders other components inside it. But I am not getting it. It still shows me {{1+1}}.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you update the tags related to your question (angularjs is for version 1.*, and angular is for angular 2+)

Comment: yes, i did that thanks!

Comment: see if you can help me out.

Comment: can you show also your main "NgModule", and your "my-app" component?

Comment: Angular does not process `{{}}` expressions in `index.html`, only in templates.

Comment: is it just the `{{}}` expression or any code related to angular wont work like directives ?

Comment: Do you see "this is hello world" inside your view?

Comment: yes @DeblatonJean-Philippe I can see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for a simple reason - whatever is inside the root component is only displayed until Angular is bootstrapped.

Given that fact, you cannot use the interpolation simply because that needs to be processed by Angular - and that is not bootstrapped yet.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a simple custom Directive example for you in Angular 2.
[Plunker SEE and play](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZrVaS87bOvSYgWHqaVjf/)

You can checkout more about Directives and custom directives at 
[Angular Directives discription](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>This is Angular1</h1>

<div ng-app>
<p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks parth! you got the right output, but at app.component.html level. I want the same at index.html directly if understood my problem correctly.

Comment: i have updated the code and Its Angular 1 .Maybe it might help you ..Please up vote if you satisfy ..

Comment: see the tags related to question. its angular and not angularjs or angular 1.x. this wont work in angular 2 obviously.

Comment: In angular 2 ..Its not possible .Let me explain.The angular is not loaded yet so you cannot do it like that way ..Because it doesn't recognize Mustache 

I had used this in my project to pass the value to directives ...
 <app-show [CName]=my_values>Loading..></app-show>
You can use angular input maybe it might help
see here
https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: I understand the user input process, but this is way ahead than this. first let angular load properly. may be that's the issues here!

Comment: Ya that's the issue here ...Loading the angular ..At Index file it doesn't recognize the angular code there ..And it is not the way angular works.Angular works in modules .Load Big part of the Website at once in one component and then put custom directives for different parts .For ex Profile loading directive ,member list directive etc...

Maybe you are trying something else but this is the right way ...
One more thing <my-app>{{1+1}}</my-app>   this will give {{1+1}} at loading time only .Once your directive|component is loaded it will be gone ..